# Unable to run ionic app on ios iPadian emulator

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I am working on `ionic1` framework. i have to built android application and its working fine on android device and also i need to run application on `iOS`.

I have installed `iPadian` emulator for this.

I have run these commands ionic platform add `iOS` than ionic build `iOS` built command gives

You cannot run`iOS` unless you are on MAC OSX.

Please help me to run app on ios i am new to ionic framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need compile your app for iOS platform, wich windows can not to do this by default. You need to install 3-rd party software (something like XCode SDK for windows) to compile in windows for iOs platform or compile it in Apple iOS device.

Comment: I have install vmware workstation  and xcode for run app on ios.   But how to run my app on this.